# How to fade-in a new screen from the bottom following the direction of a vertical drag action?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to navigate to a new screen with a fade-in animation from the bottom of the screen, following the direction of vertical drag on a custom material widget.

I have created two screens, Screen -1 and screen -2. On screen - 1, I have a Container widget. I have wrapped the widget inside a GestureDetector and I am trying Navigate to screen - 2 on vertical drag, which I am using GestureDetector.onVerticalDrag property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/':(context) => ScreenOne(),
        '/two': (context) => ScreenTwo(),
      },
      title: 'Screens',
    );
  }
}

class ScreenOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen-1'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details){
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/two');
        },
              child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen-2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Screen-2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can you please help me get the expected transition. I am attaching a GIF for reference.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm preparing my solution, hold on for 10 mins :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using PageView, this is much easier with it and Opacity widget. Here is the [demo video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJPy.jpg).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestViewState createState() => _TestViewState();
}

class _TestViewState extends State<TestView> {
  PageController pageController;
  double panPosition = 1; // dummy value prevents division with 0
  double deviceHeight;

  void updatePageState() {
    setState(() {
      panPosition =
          pageController.position.pixels.abs(); // updates pan position
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(
      keepPage: true,
    );
    pageController
        .addListener(updatePageState); // add listener to page controller.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    deviceHeight =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; //get device screen height
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, //vertical scroll
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(
            // opacity handles the transition effect
            opacity: 1 - (panPosition / deviceHeight),
            //first screen opacity goes from 1 to 0
            child: ScreenOne(),
          ),
          Opacity(
            opacity: (panPosition / deviceHeight),
            //first screen opacity goes from 0 to 1
            child: ScreenTwo(
              title: "this title is from parent widget.",
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen-1'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 96,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const ScreenTwo({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. But in the real application, where I am supposed to use this, the second screen that I am navigating to takes in some parameters, and I handle that Navigation using onGenerateRoute. Can I pass data to the second screen, using PageView?

Comment: I edited my answer. Now the second screen has `title` final variable and its value is set in TestView.

Comment: I faced the same problem, and I stumbled upon your solution. However, I tried to add more pages to it, but I couldn't. Can you help me out? Thanks..
@westdabestdb

Comment: @user10033434 yeah hit me up

Comment: thanks.. do you have an email? @westdabestdb

Comment: @user10033434 westdabestdb@gmail.com